# Adding a dark mode toggle to vuetify app v2.0 on nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt.js vuetify template, nuxt.config.js already has a object (mentioned below) which defines dark mode for the app.

```
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

How do I add this as a feature, as a button to toggle from light version to dark? Vuetify has [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme) for theme customization, but no proper way which explains how to do this within the app.

Comment: Also, check out this example for reference: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do the following on a `v-btn` to manipulate `$vuetify.theme.dark`.

```
<v-btn @click="$vuetify.theme.dark=!$vuetify.theme.dark">Toggle Theme</v-btn>
```

This will toggle between the light and dark theme.
The setting is described at the title "[Light and Dark](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme#light-and-dark)" in the documentation, though I admit it is easy to miss.

Edit: Save state in localStorage

Create a method and call it @click.

```
toggleTheme() {
   this.$vuetify.theme.dark=!this.$vuetify.theme.dark;
   localStorage.setItem("useDarkTheme", this.$vuetify.theme.dark.toString())
}
```

and on mounted you could then load that state

```
mounted() {
  const theme = localStorage.getItem("useDarkTheme");
    if (theme) {
      if (theme == "true") {
        this.$vuetify.theme.dark = true;
      } else this.$vuetify.theme.dark = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: how to store dark mode status in localStorage, and get it on app start?

Comment: @FarshidRezaei check out my edit. That's how I did it

Comment: "mounted" function where is placed? which file or component?

Comment: wherever you want the initial check for the theme to happen. If you have a login page and you want that to be dark already, then it would be that login page

Answer (score 0):

Nice and fastest way I found to add a switch button for dark/light mode:

```
<v-btn
  icon
  :color="$vuetify.theme.dark ? 'yellow' : 'dark'"
  @click="$vuetify.theme.dark = !$vuetify.theme.dark"
>
```

Nothing else needed.